# Cannot extract country code from pygal.maps.world.COUNTRIES

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function which extracts the two-digit country code from `pygal.maps.world.COUNTRIES` but it does not work consistently. My code:

```
from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES

def get_country_code(country_name):
"""Return the Pygal 2-digit country code for the given country"""
    for code, name in COUNTRIES.items():
        if name == country_name:
            return code
        # If the country wasn't found, return None.
        return None
```

When testing with the following:

```
print(get_country_code('Andorra'))
print(get_country_code('Afghanistan'))
print(get_country_code('United Arab Emirates'))
```

I get the results:

```
ad
None
None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop always returned after the first iteration, because you got the indentation of `return None` wrong, so that it was part of the `for` loop.

This should work:

```
def get_country_code(country_name):
    for code, name in COUNTRIES.items():
        if name == country_name:
            return code
    # If the country wasn't found, return None.
    return None
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but you can just use [`pycountry`](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/) to do this easily:

```
import pycountry

COUNTRIES = ['Andorra', 'Afghanistan', 'United Arab Emirates']

# Get all country mappings, using two digit codes
country_mapping = {country.name: country.alpha_2 for country in pycountry.countries}

# Map your countries
country_codes = [country_mapping.get(country) for country in COUNTRIES]

print(country_codes)
# ['AD', 'AF', 'AE']
```